# Is it possible to do a ParametersVariation, access values from main and store them in an excel after iteration?

Tags: java, anylogic

I am running a number of experiments and after the simulation is over the results are stored in an excel called excelFile.
At the moment I am doing one experiment after another, because if I use Parameter Variation I do not know how to get access to the measured values in the main from the Experiment `ParametersVariation: Main`
This is what I use in the single experiment runs with an excel in the Main :

`excelFile.createCell(1, t, 2);`

`excelFile.setCellValue(shopfloor_throughput_time.mean() ,1 , t , 2);`

But I want to run 30 experiments at the same time and have the excel in the ParameterVariations environment.
I don't know how to access the measured values in the Main from the ParametersVariation to write them into the excel in the ParametersVariation.

I tried this:

`excelFile.createCell(1, getCurrentIteration(), 1);`

`excelFile.setCellValue(main.shopfloor_throughput_time.mean() ,1 ,getCurrentIteration() , 1);`

in the ParametersVariation environment on *After iteration*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have access to `Main` in the "after simulation run" code field in your Param-Var experiment. You need to use the keyword `root` to access `Main` from there.

If you had an xls sheet "outputs" with columns "iterationNo, ReplicationNo, value", you could use code like this to store unique run results:

```
int rowIndex = 0; // increase this after every round
excelFile.setCellValue(getCurrentIteration(), "outputs", rowIndex, 0); // first column
excelFile.setCellValue(getCurrentReplication(), "outputs", rowIndex, 1); // 2nd column
excelFile.setCellValue(root.someValueToStore, "outputs", rowIndex, 2); // 3rd column
rowIndex++; // for next run
```

Likely needs some adjustments, but this is the zest